# IP_TRANSPARENT on Windows platform

Tags: windows, sockets

There is the IP_TRANSPARENT socket option on Linux. Is there a similar option for Windows platform in WinSock? Or is there any way to move Winsock's socket to transparent mode?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such thing as "transparent mode" in Windows. Proxy-related logic has to be implemented manually in code by binding a connection locally and communicating with a proxy server to connect to a remote server.